# Set scroll mode conditionally with react-full-page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently using react-full page module on my webpage. The thing is, I don't want a full-page scroll when on mobile phones or tablets, because it's weird and uncomfortable. The component, `<FullPage>` has a property called scrollMode, which can be either "normal" or "full-page".

How can I update that value dynamically? I know the property called window.innerWidth but I can't figure out how to use it, I tried using useEffect & useState but it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import ScrollToTop from "react-scroll-to-top";
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet';
import { FullPage, Slide } from 'react-full-page';

// Components //
import MainBanner from '../components/common/MainBanner';
import HomeProjects from '../components/common/HomeProjects';
import AboutMe from '../components/common/AboutMe';
import Skills from '../components/common/Skills';
import ContactCommon from '../components/common/Contact';
import Warning from '../components/common/Warning';

const Home = () => {

    let innerWidth;

    useEffect(() => {
        if(window.innerWidth <= 768) innerWidth = "normal";
        else innerWidth = "full-page";
    }, [innerWidth]);

    console.log(innerWidth);

    const [warningPage, setWarningPage] = useState(true);
    
    return ( 
        warningPage ? (<Warning setWarningPage={setWarningPage}/>) : (
            <div className="home-container">
        <Helmet>
            <title>Alejo Yanczuk - Home</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Home page | Web developer website" data-react-helmet="true"/>
        </Helmet>
        <div>

            <FullPage scrollMode={innerWidth}>
                <Slide>
                    <MainBanner />
                </Slide>
                <Slide>
                    <AboutMe />
                </Slide>
                <Slide>
                    <Skills />
                </Slide>
                <Slide>
                    <HomeProjects />
                </Slide>
                <Slide>
                    <ContactCommon />
                </Slide>
            </FullPage>

            <div>
            <ScrollToTop smooth/>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        )
    );
}
 
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a useEffect with a variable as dependancy and not a state.

You need to use a state, and create a state for innerWidth.

You need too use a `addEventListener` to listen rezize event from window.

Here is a exemple:

```js
const Home = () => {
  const [innerWidth, setInnerWidth] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    function onResize() {
      // here is a quick syntaxe to avoid if / else
      setInnerWidth(window.innerWidth <= 768 ? 'normal' : "full-page");
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", onResize)
  }, [innerWidth]);

  const [warningPage, setWarningPage] = useState(true);

  return warningPage ? (
    <Warning setWarningPage={setWarningPage} />
  )....
```

Comment: Alright, I'll try that, Thank you very much for your response!